# What does a low serum creatinine indicate?

Tags: blood-tests, creatinine

The normal serum creatinine range is [0.80-1.60] mg/dl. If a person's creatinine level is slightly less than 0.80 mg/dl, what does it indicate?

Comment: You can find causes of low creatinine levels on various websites. The problem is that often you can't make any definite conclusions without knowing other relevant laboratory results.

Comment: If you google the title of your question you'll get some general explanations, but those explanations will use words like "usually" and won't be more specific because they can't be. As @Jan pointed out, interpretations of lab results have to be made in the context of the individual and their unique circumstances.